# gcloud endpoints deploy Error with timestamp type

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I already deployed a lot of google gRPC cloud endpoints with success.

But for the first time, i'm using a timestamp type in my proto, and when i'm trying to deploy my gRPC API, i have an error :

```
gcloud endpoints deploy services api_descriptor.pb api_config.yaml

ERROR: (gcloud.endpoints.services.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Cannot 
convert to service config.
'ERROR: google/protobuf/timestamp.proto:121:1: (at document line 76) 
Unexpected end tag '--)' with missing begin tag.'
```

my command to generate api_descriptor.pb

```
protoc -I . backoffice*.proto \
--proto_path=. \
--include_imports \
--include_source_info \
--descriptor_set_out=api_descriptor.pb
```

my api_config.yaml

```
type: google.api.Service
config_version: 3

name: backoffice.endpoints.MY_PROJECT.cloud.goog

title: Backoffice gRPC API
apis:
- name: package.BackofficeApi

usage:
  rules:
  - selector: "*"
    allow_unregistered_calls: true
```

I cannot find any information about this issue ... any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a mistake in the [`timestamp.proto`](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/timestamp.proto) file, unfortunately.

It's [been fixed](https://github.com/google/protobuf/commit/92a7e778e7394386f413cec28d67a07630f784b1#diff-9bd13c5c4bf8e837faffb2159d653095), but it sounds like the protobuf release you've got doesn't have the fix in yet.

Fortunately, you can fix this locally - just edit `timestamp.proto` (wherever you've got it; that depends on which package you're using) to break the `--)` on line 121 into `--` at the end of line 121 and `)` on the next line, as it is in the current file (linked above).

Comment: OK thks for the fix.

I'm using protobuf 3.5.1.1  :

brew list protobuf --versions
protobuf 3.5.1_1

Comment: I just add a PR on brew to add the last version of protobuf : https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/26252

Answer (score 2):

It seems this problem exists in `protobuf` versions (3.5.0 - 3.5.2, as of May 9, 2018) and fix is not in any release yet. I found the problematic file at `"<python path>\Lib\site-packages\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\timestamp.proto"`

Replacing the line:

```
// http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#dateTime--)
```

with

```
// http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#dateTime)
```

solved the problem for me